# Office JS AddIn Question - Detecting Attendee Change

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I'm working on an Office JS add-in that requires detecting when creating a new appointment/meeting in Office 365 Outlook to call some function. I ran into the following on Microsoft's site:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.recipientschangedfields?view=outlook-js-1.11

I tried using:


`Office.context.mailbox.addHandlerAsync(Office.RecipientsChangedFields, function(){
...
}`

But that doesn't seem to be correct, anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set up the event handler on the `item` object, not mailbox:

```
Office.context.mailbox.item.addHandlerAsync(
            Office.EventType.RecipientsChanged,
            () => {
              console.log("Recipients changed");
            },
            (asyncResult) => {
              if (asyncResult.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed) {
                console.error(asyncResult.error);
                reject();
              } else {
                resolve();
              }
            }
          );
```

Comment: you are right, i missed the 'item', thanks!